# $l$-adic Galois representations factor through a common finite quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically connected variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Assume that for some $m>0$ we have $h^{i, 2m-i}(X)=0$ unless $i=m$.

Does there exist a number field $E$ such that for all but finitely many primes $l$ the homomorphism $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}) \to GL(H^{2m}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}, \mathbb{Q}_l(m)))$ is the composition of the natural map $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})\to \mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ and an injective map $\mathrm{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q})\to GL(H^{2m}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}, \mathbb{Q}_l(m)))$?

Comment: Are you willing to assume the Tate conjecture?

Comment: Sure, then the image of the cycle class map gives a natural Q-structure (even Z-structure) after twisting by Q_l(m).

Comment: You're supposed to take the Tate conjecture over some finite extensions $K$ of $\mathbb Q$ such that the representation is trivial after a Tate twist over $K$. Then the Galois invariant subspace is the whole space. Alternately, because you began with an assumption about Hodge numbers, you can use the Hodge conjecture.

Comment: Edited in response to comments.

Comment: As you said in your original version, this is "expected", or more precisely it follows from the Hodge conjecture, but not known.

Comment: @WillSawin wait this can't be shown unconditionally either?

Comment: I don't think so - How could it be?

Comment: You don't need the Hodge or Tate conjecture, only Deligne's conjecture that all Hodge classes are absolutely Hodge.